# Feeding dtype np.float32 to TensorFlow placeholder

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to feed an numpy ndarray of type : float32 to a TensorFlow placeholder, but it's giving me the following error:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
```

My place holders are defined as:

```
n_steps = 10
n_input = 13
n_classes = 1201

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
```

And the line it's giving me the above error is:

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

where my batch_x and batch_y are numpy ndarrays of dtype('float32').  The following are the types that I printed using pdb:

```
(Pdb)batch_x.dtype
dtype('float32')
(Pdb)x.dtype
tf.float32
```

I have also tried type-casting batch_x and batch_y to tf.float32 as it seems like x is of dtype tf.float32 but running the code with type-casting:

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: tf.to_float(batch_x), y: tf.to_float(batch_y)})
```

gives the following error:

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
```

How should I feed the placeholders? of what type should I use?
Any help/advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: What you have seems correct. Do you mind trying a smaller program? For instance, does the following work?

`z = tf.reduce_sum(x) + tf.reduce_sum(y);
sess.run(z, feed_dict={x:np.zeros([1, 10, 13]), y:np.zeros([1, 1201])})`

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem, are you sure that `batch_y` is also `float32`? You only provide the trace of the `batch_x` type, and `batch_y` is more likely to be integer, since it appears to be a one-hot encoding of your classes.

For the second problem, what you do wrong is you use `tf.to_float`, which is a tensor operation, on a regular numpy array. You should use numpy cast intstead:

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x.astype(np.float32), y: batch_y.astype(np.float32)})
```